# How to the 'base' theme in an MVC4 web app with a jQueryUI theme

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, themes

I have a standard out-of-the-box MVC4 app here using the base theme.

I also have a Themeroller zip.

How do I apply the custom jqueryui theme to to my app in place of the stock theme? Step by step instructions with an explanation of why each step is being done would be greatly appreciated and go a long way in lifting MVC4's theme fog for me.

(I am aware of question 11892182, and I have followed it exactly without meeting with success. It is a year old now and I am hoping things have gotten better between jQueryUI and MVC4)

Dave

Answer (score 1):

Jquery UI is by default embedded in your new asp.net mvc4 internet template project. In order to user the default theme.

1. Open your _Layout.cshtml file. (Views => Shared => Layout.cshtml)
2. In your header section, replace the line
    `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")`
     with this 
    `@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")`
3. Add this `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")` at the end of your Layout.cshtml file right below `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`
4. Now start using your jqueryUI widgets and theme and they will display properly.

In order to use your custom downloaded theme, you need to modify the BundleConfig.cs file (App_Start => BundleConfig.cs)

If you have the complete source of jqueryUI with seperate files. Just replace your current base theme files in base folder (Content => theme => base) with your custom theme files.

In case you have a single file for the javascript and css. modify the BundleConfig.cs code. Replace

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
```

so that the include part holds the path to your custom css file for e.g something like this

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css");
```

Comment: Where do I put the contents of the zip?  I copied the contents of the 'js' folder (3 .js files) into the Scripts folder and the zip's css/start folder into the Content/themes folder to sit beside the base folder (ie Content/themes/base and Content/themes/start)

Answer (score 0):

sherwaniusman, I tried what you suggested and I only managed to break my own CSS entirely. I have got to be missing something.  I thought I understood what was going on, but apparently not.

Let's try something different. Here is what I did. Can you tell me where I went wrong?

1. Downloaded the 'le-frog' theme from http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/
2. Opened the zip and copied the three files in the js folder to my MVC4 app's Scripts folder. The three files were: jquery-1.9.1.js, jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js, and jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js
3. Copied the 'le-frog' folder from the zip to the Content/themes folder of my app to create a Content/themes/le-frog folder. The le-frog folder contains two files and an images sub-folder. The two files are jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css and jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css
4. Edited the _Layout.cshtml to have this as the only Styles.Render in the

   @Styles.Render("~Content/themes/le-frog/css")

and this at the end of the

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

1. Edited BundleConfig.cs to point each of those symbols at the correct destination:

   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                       "~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"));

   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                       "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"));

   bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/le-frog/css").Include("~/Content/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css"));

It really seems to me this should work, but instead I get a page with no CSS styling at all.

Please... What am I missing here?

Dave

Comment: Did you view source of your page? In the header check the includes that they are working fine.

Comment: I see this in the header of the page in the browser:  <link href="/Content/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>   and this near the bottom: <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>

Comment: Click on them. They should open the file in a new tab. This shows that the files are included correctly.

Comment: Yes, clicking on the css and js links in 'View page source' do load the linked files in new tabs.

Comment: Now try adding a jqueryUI component to your page. It should style itself accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Also using the le-frog, and it is unclear which file goes where. There's no "css" folder under "Content", looks like the folder-structure has been changed between versions.

Frustrating - adding a theme should not be more difficult (nor take more time) than implementing drag & drop under WinForm.